# quadratic relationship in multiple regression

Tags: regression, nonlinear

I am running a multiple regression to test the relationship between X1 and Y. I control for X2, X3, X4,etc. Before running the regression, I plot X&Y and find that there is a quadratic relationship (reversed U) between them. The turning point is very close the mean of X1. When X value is smaller the mean, their correlation is positive; when X value is greater the mean, their correlation is negative. I try to add X1 squared to the equation, but find that X1 and X1 squared are perfectly correlated (coef.=0.98). Is there another way that I can represent their quadratic relationship in the regression?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to scale and center the variable, that might help with this issue but it can make the results more difficult to interpret. An alternative, and perhaps better, approach is to try using regression splines (generalized additive model), and you will then get a smooth curve that describes the relationship between X1 and Y. In R code:

```
library(mgcv)
M1 <- gam (Y ~ s(X1) + X2 + X3, family=gaussian)
plot(M1)
```

Comment: @Jonas Berge: Do you mean that regression splines and gam are the same thing ?

Comment: @f coppens: No, they're not entirely the same thing. Spline regression is a technique for modeling non-linear relationships in the context of regression models, and is an alternative to polynomial regression. Gam is a regression model that permits the use of regression splines in a generalized linear model framework, but there is also gamm (the mixed model variant) and I think there are variants of Cox regression as well that allows for regression splines. So no, they are not the same thing. Sorry for the sloppiness.